# How to hide a div on mobile but make it visible with jQuery

Tags: jquery, media-queries, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have a project with `ZURB Foundation 5` and `jQuery`.

Just for mobile users, I have a situation, where I want a `<div>` to be hidden on the page load, but it should become visible when the user clicks on an element. Note that the specified element must be visible for non mobile users.

Tried

```
<div id="inithidden" class="show-for-medium-up">contents of the hidden div</div>
```

and

```
<a href="#/" onclick="$('#inithidden').toggle(); return false;">Click to show the hidden div</a>
```

but it does not work.

Tried also the `visible-for-medium-up` class on the `#inithidden` without any luck.

Is there a way to accomplish this without the use of javascript?

Comment: jQuery is javascript...

Comment: I mean without the use of JS to initially hide the div...

Comment: Sorry for not so good english :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: You say you want jQuery in your answer, and "without the use of javascript" --- but jQuery is a JS library.

---

If `#inithidden` is hidden `display:none` on page load, then you can change the `onclick` in the second line of code to:

```
$('#inithidden').show();
```

What your code is doing is simply creating a jQuery object for `$("#inithidden")`, but not doing anything with it. Use `show()` to change `display` to `block`.

---

**EDIT** Looking at your comment, if you are just asking how to set it to hidden by default, you can either add the style:

```
div#inithidden { display: none; }
```

to your CSS, or you can add the `style` attribute to your `<div>` like so:

```
<div style="display: none;" id="inithidden" class="show-for-medium-up">contents of the hidden div</div>
```

---

**EDIT 2**: Seeing your second comment, you can do this through CSS's `@media` rule, like so:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
    div#inithidden { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: My friend, I want it to be visible on page load to non-mobile users :)